# How to get rid of adjacent String inside arraylist?

Tags: java

what command of arraylist should I use in order to get rid of adjacent Strings. Suppose I have an arraylist of `allOrders<String>`:

```
Crushed Turtle
10 Coins Off
10 Coins Off
Mushroom Veal
```

In the example above I should not get 2 adjacent lines of the same thing. What method of arraylist should I use?

Note: only adjacent should be removed/replaced. The following is legit:

```
Firey Flower Pasta
Crushed Turtle
Firey Flower Pasta
Crushed Turtle
```

Comment: you wanna remove duplicates for all ?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Why are you getting adjacent duplicate strings in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get an Iterator from your List, iterate over the entire list and keep track of the latest value. If the current value is equal to the latest, you delete it.

Something like this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = allOrders.iterator();
String latest = "";
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String current = iterator.next();
  if (current.equals(latest)) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
  latest = current;
}
```

Comment: Is there no risk of concurrent exception?

Comment: No, since you use iterator.remove(). If you, say, kept track of the index and did allOrders.delete(index), in the iterating loop, that would be something else.

Comment: This will not work if the `List` is immutable. It's possible to create an  immutable `ArrayList` (by extending it).

Comment: That's true of course. If that's the case, then there are other answers to pick from.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own loop which will iterate over pair of elements and if they are equal remove one of them (you can use `remove(index)` from `List`).

```
for (int i=list.size()-1; i>0; i--){
    if (list.get(i-1).equals(list.get(i))){
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I prefer to iterate from end to start to avoid problems with elements shifting.

DEMO:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Crushed Turtle");
list.add("10 Coins Off");
list.add("10 Coins Off");
list.add("10 Coins Off");
list.add("Mushroom Veal");

for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i - 1).equals(list.get(i))) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output: `[Crushed Turtle, 10 Coins Off, Mushroom Veal]`

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method for doing what you want, but you could create a stripped copy (`stripped`) of your list like this:

```
List<String> stripped = new ArrayList<String>();
String latestOrder = null;

for (String order : allOrders) {
    if (!order.equals(latestOrder)) {
        stripped.add(order);
    }
    latestOrder = order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. You iterate over the `List` and compare consecutive elements if two equals you remove one of them.

```
 ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("d");
        System.out.println(l);
        for(int i = 0; i < l.size() - 1; i++){
            if(l.get(i).equals(l.get(i+1))){
                l.remove(i+1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(l);
```